# Set offset when click on anchor with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I know this question is allready on stackoverflow and I also have my solution from here. But there is still a small problem with it.

I have a small submenu thats fixed to top, so when I click on an anchor-link I want the anchor after the submenu.

First my code, this works in most cases:

```
function offsetSubmenu() {
    if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - submenuHeight);
    }
}
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    offsetSubmenu();
});
window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetSubmenu();
}, 1);
```

You see the code is executed once when the page is loaded and everytime the hash in url change. And it works so far. The problem is when the hash don't change. For example when u click on first Hashlink, scroll around and then again klick on that link the hash does not change and so windowscroll jumps to the anchor without the offset of the submenu.

A clicklistener does not work, cause `$("a").click(..)` is executed before the browser jumps to the anchor.

Any idea how I can handle the offset for anchors when the hashtag does not change?

Comment: Have you tried using a `setTimeout(offsetSubmenu, 1)` on the `$("a").click(...)`? (the same way as you execute `offsetSubmenu` the first time)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro very nice. Write it in an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$("a").click(...)` is executed before the browser jumps to the anchor, add a small delay to the offsetMenu call so it is executed after the jump. Something like:

```
setTimeout(offsetSubmenu, 1)
```

(the same way as you execute offsetSubmenu the first time)